# Mouse stops working correctly after windows 10 pc goes to screensaver

Tags: windows, windows-10, mouse, screensaver, right-click

When ever I leave my PC alone long enough for it to go to screensaver and log back in, my mouse no longer right-clicks, and when I try to left-click to open a window, it brings up multiple copies of what I am trying to open.

Also, when I bring up the Start Menu, the Sleep button is blurred and unclickable. I usually do a restart, and this fixes it until the next time it goes to screensaver. I have also tried the Windows 10 full reset.